# why request hit controller's method but not AbstractController's method?

Tags: oop, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC, I know that generally we design a controller to implement "Controller", but I write below code, the result is "Hello World 1" but not "Hello World 2", then anyone can tell me why not "Hello World 2 " ?

**that's : why request invoked the method what we implements (Controller) but not that we extends (AbstractController) ?**

thanks.

```
package com.somesite.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractController implements Controller{

@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("msg","Hello World 1");
    mv.setViewName("hello");
    return mv;
}
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("msg","Hello World 2");
    mv.setViewName("hello");
    return mv;
}
```

}

my controller config as below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
">

<!-- HandlerMapping -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

<!-- HandlerAdapter -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>

<!-- ViewResolver -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- controller -->
<bean name="/hello" class="com.somesite.controller.HelloWorldController"/>
```

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that using `Controller` is more or less depracted in favor of `@Controller`. Are you sure you are using the most recent version of your controller. Try adding `@Override` to the `handleRequest` method, if it isn't called it doesn't match the method signature as noted in the `Controller` interface.

Comment: actually I am learning spring mvc, so I think I should know not only annotation style, but also xml config style. thanks M.Deinum

Comment: And what has the use of `Controller` or `@Controller` to do with the fact that you use XML or annotation/java based configuration. The way you implement your components has nothing to do with HOW you configure them.

Comment: em, will try to keep ur suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is API design,if you see

Controller interface --->

```
public interface Controller {
    org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView handleRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception;
}
```

Now if you see AbstractController abstract class,it implements Controller interface itself,and it contains  **implementation** of **handleRequest** method.
with last statement as follow.

```
return handleRequestInternal(request, response);



public abstract class AbstractController extends org.springframework.web.servlet.support.WebContentGenerator implements org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller {
    private boolean synchronizeOnSession;

    public AbstractController() { /* compiled code */ }

    public final void setSynchronizeOnSession(boolean synchronizeOnSession) { /* compiled code */ }

    public final boolean isSynchronizeOnSession() { /* compiled code */ }

    public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView handleRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws java.lang.Exception { /* compiled code */ }

    protected abstract org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception;
}
```

And one more thing you can see one more comment there.

**Template method. Subclasses must implement this. The contract is the same as for handleRequest.** (just above the handleRequestInternal declaration).It means every controller which extends AbstractController will have to provide the implementation of 
handleRequestInternal method.

So in order to execute the request Spring MVC would need to create the Object of the class which further extends the **AbstractController** class, and provide the implementation of **handleRequestInternal** method.

Here you are extending both **AbstractController** and **Controller**,which is not correct because as you can see AbstractController itself implements Controller interface.

So if you want to execute the handleRequest() method of your controller,i think you will have to implement only Controller interface not to extend AbstractController class

Comment: why I see the source code for AbstractController, it implements the handRequest method ? not blank implementation ?  as here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractController.java

Comment: Indeed you are right,it contains compiled code section

Comment: thanks for ur reply, although  not very agree ur words